# jQuery custom scrollbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the jquery custom scrollbar plugin.

My html:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:10000px"></div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("body").customScrollbar();
});
```

Yes, I linked jquery, the js and css file.
When I load the page, it is blank. Without the javascript, it is fine.
The plugin can be found here:
http://plugins.jquery.com/custom-scrollbar/

Comment: Can you look in the console and see if its giving any error messages?

Comment: Clarify what's exactly _"not working"_

Comment: The page is blank, and not blank as in I didn't put anything into the div. In "inspect elemtn", the height of body is "0". No errors in the console.

Comment: Try giving your body a height and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @user2070057 Tried that.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Also, what if you specified a width?

Comment: I would recommend using [`fakescroll`](https://github.com/yairEO/fakescroll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the skin in the `body` and set `width` and `height` in pixels. Percentages or use of [CSS3 calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) doesn't works (if you set the width and height in body). Maybe you would have to modify the CSS to get better results.

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="modern-skin">
    <div style="height:10000px">asdf SAS</div>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("body").customScrollbar({updateOnWindowResize:true});
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Look! it's just a band-aid.

If you need a better solution, I recommend you to implement this example from [plugin website](http://jquery-custom-scrollbar.rocketmind.pl/resizing.html). Here's an example of how to adjust the scrollbar to the window size.